# Ajax doesn't execute success function in django dynamic data retrieval upon page scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to load 35 records in the initial load and upon page scroll down, next 35 records should get populated. But Unfortunately, initial load of 35 entries are populated, when I scroll down the page, nothing happens (next 35 records are not getting populated.) - I could see only the message and loader image 'We are loading more tickets'.. Please help, Thanks

**Views.py :**

```
def table_row(request, start=0, count=35): #set count here for how many ticket to load each call. Set it so it loads slightly more than enough to fill a page. 
if request.method == 'POST':
     filter =  request.POST.get('category', False)
     if filter:
        tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(category=filter)
else:
     tickets = Ticket.objects.all()
start = int(start)
return render_to_response('table-view.html',
     {
             'tickets':tickets[start:start+count], #slices the index of tickets to return
     }, RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py :**

```
url(r'^table-view/$', 'app.views.table_row', name='table-view'),
```

**table-view.html**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #main-window{
    overflow: auto;
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='filter-bar'>
    <select>
         <option value='bug'>Bugs</option>
         <option value='estimate'>Estimates</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id='main-window'>  
     <table id='full-table'>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                   <th>Ticket ID</th>
                   <th>Ticket Title</th>
                   <th>User</th>
                   <th>Description</th>
                   <th>Date</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id='table-body'>
              {% for ticket in tickets %}
   <tr class='ticket'>
        <td>{{ ticket.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ ticket.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ ticket.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ ticket.description}}</td>
        <td>{{ ticket.date }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
          </tbody>
     </table> 
      <!--The loading animation. Appears on first page load and every time the scrolling reaches the bottom -->
     <div id='text-loading'> 
          We are loading more tickets 
<img src="../../static/app/img/ajax-loader.gif" />
      </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var processing;
function loadTickets(){
     //the ajax call to load more tickets into the table
     var ticket_count= $('tr.ticket').length; //grabs the number of data results returned
     $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url:'{% url 'app.views.table_row' %}'+ticket_count+'/'+,
          data:{
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken':getCookie('csrftoken'), //This is the ajax csrf protection function 
          },
          success:function(data){
               $('#text-loading').toggleClass('hidden',true); //hides the loading animation when ajax call returns tickets
               $('#table-body').append(data); //adds data to the end of the table
               processing = false; // the processing variable prevents multiple ajax calls when scrolling
          }
     });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     loadTickets(); //initial ticket load
     $('#main-window').scroll(function(e){
          if (processing){
              return false;
          }
          if ($('#content-window').scrollTop() >= ($('#full-table').height() -$('#content-window').height())){
              processing = true; //prevent multiple scrolls once first is hit
              $('#text-loading').toggleClass('hidden', false); //show the loading animation
              loadTickets();
          } 
     });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you shoud somehow count the tickets you have so you can pass them to the php, the curent logic if implemented succesfuly will load the same 35 artilce the first and the second time

Comment: 35 records were getting loaded (which means ticket count is being captured).  but my page scroll down event doesn't work I think.. I'm not sure if the logic in javascript is correct ? ($('#content-window').scrollTop() >= ($('#full-table').height() -$('#content-window').height())){...}   content-window is not in place at the moment.. Should I add it after main-window or is this Ajax pre defined element ?